# Delimit data (JSON) with newline when sending to server over socket using NSOutputStream

Tags: ios, ios5, tcp, nsstream, nsoutputstream

I'm making a TCP protocol where an app sends JSON to a server and it sends JSON back. I am trying to delimit each transmission with a newline. This is fine on the server side, but how do you add a newline to each NSOutputStream write?

The streams are set-up correctly and here's the code I'm using to send data:

```
NSInteger sendJSON = [NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:dictionary toStream:self.outputStream options:0 error:nil];
```

How do you add a newline (`\n`) to the end of that, surely there's a way?

Comment: Have you tried `options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`?

Comment: @Binyamin - Yep, that just adds a lot of unnecessary whitespace around the JSON. Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not forgetting that Objective C is a strict superset of C the simplest solution could be to add a new line after invoking the code in your question:

```
const char* newLine = "\n";
if (self.outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable) {
    [self.outputStream write:(const uint8_t*)newLine maxLength:1];
}
```